# Including a file in two locations for a web application in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nlog

I have a project, `MyCompany.Common`, which does a number of things, including providing a common logging framework that uses [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). Inside `MyCompany.Common`, there is an `NLog.config` file that defines some standard logging targets, and basically a configuration framework of sorts, which includes files from some default (specific to my app) locations, like `C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\global.log.config`. `Nlog.config` is set to *Copy Always*.

The result of this is that when `MyCompany.Common` gets included in any other project, `NLog.config` and `NLog.dll` get deployed to the application directory, and everything Just Works.

However, when `MyCompany.Common` gets referenced in a web application, the Nlog.* files go into the `bin\` directory, while NLog expects the files in the root of the web application folder.

I tried adding a Link to the file, which works great when it gets deployed (the copy from `MyCompany.Common` gets copied to the root of the web app dir), but doesn't work while Visual studio is debugging.

Short of outright copying the file (which would mean there are 2+ potentially different versions -- and 2+ spots to update), is there any way to set this file up so it ends up in the web app root?

Comment: I'm assuming NLog has no way to tell it where to look?  What's your deployment method?

Comment: It's hardcoded. One thought I had is to modify nlog to also look in ./bin/ for the file.  Deployment is done using a web deployment project, and then an msbuild script that packages it all up and builds an installer.